# Unable to access Objects in a JavaScript Array - result is undefined when accessing object by Index

Tags: javascript, asp.net, model-view-controller

Having issues accessing the object at an index of the array which results from the Ajax call. I assumed that the object at index 0 would display when I write "console.log(data[0])" but I get undefined. Any assistance would be appreciated.

```
function getBarChartData() {

        $.ajax({
            url: "/Dashboard/CarClassAvailability",
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) { 
                console.log(data);
                console.log(data[0]); // this results in undefined


            }
        });       
    }
```

```
Chrome Developer tools results

{data: Array(5)}
data: Array(5)
0: {Id: 15, Make: "Chevrolet", Model: "Malibu ", HasAutomaticTransmission: true, SeatingCapacity: 5, …}
1: {Id: 16, Make: "Ford", Model: "Mustang", HasAutomaticTransmission: false, SeatingCapacity: 4, …}
2: {Id: 17, Make: "Mini", Model: "Countryman", HasAutomaticTransmission: false, SeatingCapacity: 5, …}
3: {Id: 18, Make: "Volkswagen", Model: "Jetta", HasAutomaticTransmission: true, SeatingCapacity: 5, …}
4: {Id: 19, Make: "Kia", Model: "Forte", HasAutomaticTransmission: true, SeatingCapacity: 5, …}length: 5__proto__: Array(0)__proto__: Object
(index):315 undefined
```

Comment: console.log(data) outputs an object with key alue pairs as {data: Array(5)}, hence you need to access the zero th index element as data.data[0]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *data* array you are looking for is inside *data* object. Try

```
console.log(data.data[0]);
```

Comment: Thank you! That did it.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting the wrong index, since you have 'data' inside the parameter 'data' in the success function, try using:

```
success: function (data) { //<- this data have a property called data
            console.log(data);
            console.log(data.data[0]); //<-- try this
        }
```